# Cocoapods - Class missing from framework headers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a project a simple podfile, which includes 2 pods:

```
target 'Cocoapods Test app' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'Simple-KeychainSwift'
end
```

The correct versions of both pods are installed. All good so far.

Both pods have a single source file, and when building, class `Reachability` is added to `ReachabilitySwift-Swift.h` in its framework Headers.

BUT class `Keychain` is NOT added to `Simple_KeychainSwift-Swift.h` (so isn't visible in the main app)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it only happen to "Simple-KeychainSwift"? I suspect it is because of the hyphen "-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pod is broken. Since pods are treated as modules, all symbols that should be accessible from outside need to be marked as public. The class is not marked as public.

Comment: You, Sir, are a bloody genius! Have 100 points (in 21 hours), and my thanks!

Comment: Haha, thanks. I didn't even notice that you're the maintainer. Sorry about the duplicate issue.